# Проблема при генерации PDF файла с помощью PHP

Tags: pdf, php, fpdf, png

Задача: нужно конвертировать base64 код PNG изображения, полученный из textarea, в PNG изображение (бинарный файл с расширением .png - image.png) с помощью PHP и сохранить полученное изображение на сервере. Затем с помощью PHP и класса FPDF сгенерировать PDF файл ([example1.pdf](http://example1.pdf)), вставив в него сохраненное ранее PNG изображение. Полученный PDF файл также сохранить на сервере.

Вот файл createPdfFromBase64.php, который у меня получился:

```
<?php
    #header('Content-Type: image/png');

    $base64 = $_POST['base64']; // Получаем base64 код PNG изображения из <textarea id="base64" name="base64"></textarea>

    #echo("$base64");

    $base64 = str_replace(' ','+',$base64); // If you want to save data that is derived from a Javascript canvas.toDataURL() function, you have to convert blanks into plusses. If you do not do that, the decoded data is corrupted.

    $data = base64_decode($base64); // Декодирует данные base64 и записывает их в переменную $data

    echo("$data");

    $filename = "image.png";

    // Пишем содержимое в файл image.png
    file_put_contents($filename, $data); // Сохраняем изображение image.png на сервере

    // Подключаем класс FPDF, для генерации PDF документа
    require('/home/u552896297/public_html/FPDF/fpdf.php');

    // Создаем FPDF объект
    $pdf= new FPDF();

    // Устанавливаем свойства документа
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Evgeniy Privalov'); // Устанавливаем автора PDF документа.
    $pdf->SetTitle('PDF generator'); // Устанавливаем title PDF документа.

    // Настройки страницы. Теперь когда главное сделано, приступим к созданию страницы.
    $pdf->AddPage('P'); // Книжная ориентация страницы
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real','default'); //Функция SetDisplayMode определяет как будет отображена страница. Вы можете определить параметры увеличения и разметки. В примере мы используем 100% увеличение и разметку по умолчанию, определенную в программе, используемой для просмотра.

    // Вставляем PNG картинку в верхний левый угол с разрешением в 300 точек на дюйм (300dpi)
    $pdf->Image('image.png', 10, 10, -300);

    // В конце мы выведем наш результат используя функцию Output
    $pdf->Output('example1.pdf', 'F'); // Здесь мы указали имя файла и параметр вывода, в данном случае "F". "F"-параметр сохранит результат в файл example1.pdf
?>
```

Файл index.html лежит тут - http://print-online.16mb.com/. Нужно сначала нажать кнопку "Сохранить визитку", а затем нажать кнопку "Конвертировать в PDF".

Но при генерации PDF, выдается ошибка ***FPDF error: Not a PNG file: image.png***

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему!

**UPD:** Файл image.png создается на сервере, однако он не отображается в браузере! http://print-online.16mb.com/image.png

Comment: Если ничего не заполнять то - выдает ошибку `FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream`

-----------------

Видимо нужно смотреть обработчик и что ему нехватает!

Comment: Да, если просто нажать кнопку "конвертировать в PDF", без нажатия кнопки "Сохранить визитку", то выдает ошибку "FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream". Думаете проблема кроется в классе FPDF?

Comment: Разобрался с ошибкой "FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream", класс FPDF лежит в папке /FPDF/fpdf.php, но если я его подключаю вот так - require('/FPDF/fpdf.php');, то выдает ошибку PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '../FPDF/fpdf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20

Подскажите как правильно подключить файл, который лежит в другой папке?

Comment: ну например `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/FPDF/fpdf.php');`

Comment: Решил проблему, прописав полный путь к файлу, по другому не хотело работать на этом хостинге!

Но при попытке конвертировать в PDF выдает ошибку  FPDF error: Not a PNG file: image.png

А если отправить пустое поле textarea, то пишет FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream

Comment: Как думаете может быть, что вся проблема заключается в том, что класс FPDF не поддерживает UTF-8, а у меня base64 код PNG файла в кодировке UTF-8. Как думаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через content-type не сделаешь изображение. Можно попробовать через библиотеку GD. Может вот эта статья поможет http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1333